# "Exact dupe" vs "dupe"

Tags: discussion

On questions marked as a duplicate, the banner will sometimes say it "was marked as duplicate", and sometimes it will say it "was marked as an exact duplicate"

But when flagging, there's no option to provide whether it's exact or not.

Who decides which it is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6179/what-is-the-meaning-of-exact-duplicates-of-other-answers?rq=1

Comment: Hmmm.... I never noticed that before, two things to consider, the `exact` one is old, perhaps the message was updated? or the `exact` one was closed by jokerdino and he is a mod? I don't know for sure but the first one been old and the reason been updated seems likely to me.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Here's a newer example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/713301/how-to-install-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: @MarkKirby - And another: http://askubuntu.com/questions/714219/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-windows-tablet

Comment: Well, I guess that proves me wrong then, I don't know, we will have to wait and see I guess.

Comment: @MarkKirby - I guess he didn't read the comments before posting an answer.

Comment: He probably wrote it while we were discussing it and missed the end of the conversation. I total get why he got that conclusion though, he should of left the answer for reference though IMO.

Comment: I think one of those voters might have picked a different close reason.

Comment: @muru - Could you extrapolate? (I don't have enough rep to VTC)

Comment: @muru That makes sense, an exact = 5 dupe votes but a standard dupe = 3/4 out of 5 dupe votes.

Comment: @AndroidDev one or two of those voters might have picked unclear, off-topic, or too broad (other close reasons)

Comment: @AndroidDev When 5 close votes are cast the system goes with the most voted reason, so 3 unclear and 2 dupe = unclear and 2 unclear + 3 dupe = a dupe and 5 dupe votes = an exact dupe.

Comment: @muru - Should we wait for a mod's opinion, or do you want to go ahead and add an answer?

Comment: @AndroidDev only a dev can really answer it I think. Try searching in [meta.se], maybe someone has already asked about this.

Comment: Exact is the old wording. I'm not sure exactly when it changed but that's what it is.

Comment: @Seth - but I've provided examples that were closed in 2015 with the exact wording.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Another with the exact wording that was closed just minutes ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/781319/only-one-key-not-working-after-logged-in-duplicated

Comment: On that one at least, the difference is, the OP accepted the dupe (community user close) but that just complicates things further because they did not on any of the others :/.

Comment: @MarkKirby - I don't think I'm going to accept an answer until Oli gives an opinion.

Comment: I think, the answer below is right with the edit made, see my comment for some evidence. I don't think oli could add anything that seth could not, they are both mods. As far as I know there is no top mod kind of user.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Here's another one that has the "exact" wording, and it also has no answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/781356/strange-situation-with-linux-permissions

Comment: Possible duplicate of.... JK.

Comment: @Fiksdal - Huh?

Comment: @AndroidDev just a joke :) I was pretending to mark your question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Fiksdal - Ohhhh... Now that I have the context, I know what JK stands for :)

Answer (score 5):

[Seth](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15470/exact-dupe-vs-dupe#comment28527_15470) is partially right here. There are two different reasons that the "exact duplicate" would be shown:

1. The question was closed as a duplicate a while ago (specifically [before about February 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux))
2. The question that was closed as a duplicate had no upvoted answers.

You can read more about this in [animuson's Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197452/what-decides-what-to-prepend-the-duplicate-question-list-with-on-a-duplicate-que/197454#197454) (which I've quoted the relevant parts):

> > **Possible Duplicate:**
> >     [list]
>
> Appears on *old* questions that were marked as duplicates before the
>   new closing overhaul. These notices were edited directly into the
>   question by the Community user and could be freely edited and even
>   removed. This has since been replaced, but questions that previously
>   had it were not updated.
>
> > **This question already has an answer here:**
> >     [list]
>
> The new default message that is shown to everyone when a question gets
>   closed as a duplicate. It is an automatic box that is displayed and
>   cannot be edited.
>
> ...
>
> > **This question is an exact duplicate of:**
> >     [list]
>
> Looks like this is a special case for when you close as a duplicate of
>   another question that doesn't have any upvoted answers.

Comment: "when you close as a duplicate of another question that doesn't have any upvoted answers." I though we could not do that? When you try to close a question as a duplicate of a question without an upvoted  answer a message pops up `This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer` and it rejects the vote, until you vote on an answer. Would this just apply in special case, like, closed by a mod or a user with a gold tag badge?

Comment: @MarkKirby - And furthermore, this one wasn't closed by a mod: http://askubuntu.com/questions/714219/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-windows-tablet

Comment: @MarkKirby Hrm, then it must be the other way around: that the question that was closed as a duplicate had no upvoted answers.

Comment: @hichris123 - I think we need to wait for Oli to weigh in.

Comment: Perhaps, that does correlate, all the `exact` linked here dupes have 0 answers and this one has one answer but no votes http://askubuntu.com/questions/249542/duplicate-sources. This one with an answer and a vote http://askubuntu.com/questions/111885/application-to-find-duplicate-mp3s does have the other close reason, I think you may very well of solved the issue here.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Here's one that happened just now: my answer was upvoted, and it **doesn't** have the "exact" wording: http://askubuntu.com/questions/781476/is-it-possible-to-mount-an-iso-in-writable-mode/781481#781481